# Burn the [java-native-library] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There is no such thing as a "Java Native library", and therefore [java-native-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-native-library) should be burned or merged with [java-native-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-native-interface).

I guess this might stem from the misconception, which some uneducated web developers have about "Android Native", when talking about the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). An emulation is the very opposite of running on hardware; at least in my vocabulary.

Comment: And "JVM" stands for "Java Virtual Machine", I reckon...(?)

Comment: I agree with this suggestion. It is my first time to see that tag or term,even though I always use JNI for my programs. Even in the JNI books that I have.

Comment: Maybe the SO dev means the .dll or .so library JNI makes.

Comment: (Shouldn't that semicolon be an [em dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/em_dash#Noun) or something?)